# Terminating Pexip in Twilio

Tags: twilio

We are attempting to set up our Pexip Account to make outbound calls to our Twilio account.  We successfully have Pexip connecting to Twilio, but are receiving a "407 Proxy Authentication Required".  Has anyone successfully been able to have their Pexip account call out to Twilio over SIP?

```
2021-02-04T14:58:20.140+00:00 pexipconf 2021-02-04 14:58:20,140 Level="INFO" Name="support.sip" Message="Received SIP response" Src-address="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" Src-port="5060" Dst-address="10.0.0.11" Dst-port="5060" Transport="UDP" Received-time="2021-02-04T14:58:20,137446" Detail="
SIP/2.0 100 trying -- your call is important to us
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5060;branch=z9hG4bKf6XLw5U0Ib3YViSKD71cZkM82EoBeQvJ;rport=5060;received=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
From: "ROOM1" <sip:meet.room1@10.0.0.11>;tag=vtHb5o3sipqLRM9d;epid=jWcA8h3fGrxnbv26
To: <sip:+XXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.pstn.twilio.com>
CSeq: 1710901904 INVITE
Call-ID: 3d3600ea-62bb-4252-aae7-8b243c22fb12
Server: Twilio Gateway
Content-Length: 0

"

2021-02-04T14:58:20.150+00:00 pexipconf 2021-02-04 14:58:20,150 Level="INFO" Name="support.sip" Message="Received SIP response" Src-address="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" Src-port="5060" Dst-address="10.0.0.11" Dst-port="5060" Transport="UDP" Received-time="2021-02-04T14:58:20,147110" Detail="
SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication required
CSeq: 1710901904 INVITE
Call-ID: 3d3600ea-62bb-4252-aae7-8b243c22fb12
From: "ROOM1" <sip:meet.room1@10.0.0.11>;tag=vtHb5o3sipqLRM9d;epid=jWcA8h3fGrxnbv26
To: <sip:+XXXXXXXXXX@xyvid.pstn.twilio.com>;tag=90026019_6772d868_2f8d0dd6-90f4-42aa-a165-2e00e5964f5a
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5060;received=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;branch=z9hG4bKf6XLw5U0Ib3YViSKD71cZkM82EoBeQvJ;rport=5060
Server: Twilio
Contact: <sip:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5060>
Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="sip.twilio.com",qop="auth",nonce="mac-Uxca9fW-9FggC2z8lZSbd2KgmidgS66hPf-NStrNhtY1",opaque="b90d5a4f4492449aecc8caf7bc58e864"
Content-Length: 0

"

2021-02-04T14:58:20.153+00:00 pexipconf 2021-02-04 14:58:20,152 Level="INFO" Name="support.sip" Message="Sending SIP request" Src-address="10.0.0.11" Src-port="5060" Dst-address="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" Dst-port="5060" Transport="UDP" Detail="
ACK sip:+XXXXXXXXXX@xyvid.pstn.twilio.com SIP/2.0
From: "ROOM1" <sip:meet.room1@10.0.0.11>;tag=vtHb5o3sipqLRM9d;epid=jWcA8h3fGrxnbv26
Call-ID: 3d3600ea-62bb-4252-aae7-8b243c22fb12
To: <sip:+XXXXXXXXXX@xyvid.pstn.twilio.com>;tag=90026019_6772d868_2f8d0dd6-90f4-42aa-a165-2e00e5964f5a
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5060;branch=z9hG4bKf6XLw5U0Ib3YViSKD71cZkM82EoBeQvJ;rport
CSeq: 1710901904 ACK
Content-Length: 0

"
```

Phone numbers and IP addresses changed to protect the innocent.

We do have our Pexip IP address listed in the IP ACL of our Twilio account.

Answer (score 0):

Did you defined a Credential List on your Elastic SIP Trunk? The `407 Proxy Authentication required` is asking your SIP User Agent to respond back with its authentication credentials (username and password).